# Google spreadsheets script onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a very simple question.

I´ve found this script that works perfect, and i don´t know programming.
This script searches for any **date** value in an specific column inside the sheet called **Needed** and when it detects it then it moves the that row to another sheet called **Acquired**. I just need to do the same with other source sheets.
For example: I have 4 sheets called Needed1, Needed2, Needed3 and Needed4. All of them have to move the the rows where a date is entered to the same Acquired sheet. I hope someone could help me.

```
function onEdit() {
  // moves a row from a sheet to another sheet when a date is entered in a column
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 24 September 2014
  // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/wtzlc_ludTw/discussion

  var sheetToWatch = "Needed";
  var columnNumberToWatch = /* column G */ 4; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var sheetToMoveTheRowTo = "Acquired";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if ( sheet.getName() == sheetToWatch && cell.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && cell.getValue() instanceof Date) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(cell.getRow());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

```
function onEdit() {

  var sheetsToWatch = ["Needed1", "Needed2", "Needed3", "Needed4"];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
    var sheetToWatch = sheetsToWatch[i]; 

    // all good code goes here

  }     
}
```

And the whole code is:

```
function onEdit() {
  // moves a row from a sheet to another sheet when a date is entered in a column
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 24 September 2014
  // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/wtzlc_ludTw/discussion

  var sheetsToWatch = ["Needed1", "Needed2", "Needed3", "Needed4"];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
    var sheetToWatch = sheetsToWatch[i];
    var columnNumberToWatch = /* column G */ 4; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
    var sheetToMoveTheRowTo = "Acquired";

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    if ( sheet.getName() == sheetToWatch && cell.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && cell.getValue() instanceof Date) {
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToMoveTheRowTo);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
      sheet.deleteRow(cell.getRow());
    }

  }

}
```

You may add new sheet names into array:

```
var sheetsToWatch = ["Needed1", "Needed2", "Needed3", "Needed4", "New Name"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much Max!!

I have one last question: How can i replace the Date entered with whatever i want? For example a number or simple text? Is that possible in a easy way? Thank you!

Comment: This part of code ` && cell.getValue() instanceof Date` checks if entered value is date. If you delete it, any type of entry would be replaced.